# jquery val() is not showing value of span

Tags: jquery

Here i am trying to get value of span that is 1 here `.text()` is showing proper value but `.val()` is not showing anyting

```
<span class="commentpageno" id="commentpageno_1111" style="visibility: hidden">1</span>  

 $('.commentpageno').click(function (e) {
     alert($('.comment_page_no').text());
     alert($('.comment_page_no').val());
 });
```

Comment: Well it doesn't have a *value* thats why. Moreover why do you need to use `.val()` when `.text()` is giving it to you?

Comment: Form elements use `.val()`, not spans.

Comment: It's `visibility is hidden` how are you able to click it???

Comment: $('.comment_page_no') different from your class
`<span class="commentpageno" id="commentpageno_1111"
                   style="visibility: hidden">1
   </span>`

Comment: Initially I tried to get values from `val()` then i tried `text()`. now I got the answer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) is not used for span or div it is used for input control like text, checkbox etc

> The **.val()** method is primarily used to get the values of form elements
>   such as input, select and textarea. In the case of  elements, the .val() method returns an array
>   containing each selected option; if no option is selected, it returns
>   null, [**jQuery docs**](http://api.jquery.com/val/)
>
> The **.text()** method cannot be used on form inputs or scripts. To set or
>   get the text value of input or textarea elements, use the .val()
>   method. To get the value of a script element, use the .html() method, **[jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/text/)**

Comment: If you are using ASP.NET, be aware that asp.net label is translated to span in HTML. That means to get or set its text, please use **.text()** instead.

Answer (score 6):

Your class name is `commentpageno` and you are listening on `comment_page_no`

Do

```
alert($('.commentpageno').text());
```

as `.val()` would not work for span.